# Serialize XML with XML string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have to produce the following XML

```
<object>
    <stuff>
        <body>
            <random>This could be any rondom piece of unknown xml</random>
        </body>
    </stuff>
</object>
```

I have mapped this to a class, with a body property of type string.

If I set the body to the string value: "`<random>This could be any rondom piece of unknown xml</random>`"

The string gets encoded during serialization. How can I not encode the string so that it gets written as raw XML?

I will also want to be able to deserialize this.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Opps, justed added the .NET and C# tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` will simply not trust you to produce valid xml from a `string`. If you want a member to be ad-hoc xml, it must be something like `XmlElement`. For example:

```
[XmlElement("body")]
public XmlElement Body {get;set;}
```

with `Body` an `XmlElement` named `random` with `InnerText` of `"This could be any rondom piece of unknown xml"` would work.

---

```
[XmlRoot("object")]
public class Outer
{
    [XmlElement("stuff")]
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}
public class Inner
{
    [XmlElement("body")]
    public XmlElement Body { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(
           "<random>This could be any rondom piece of unknown xml</random>");
        var obj = new Outer {Inner = new Inner { Body = doc.DocumentElement }};

        new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you seem quite clued up on xml serilization, and chance you can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853082/custom-xml-serialization

Comment: Cool solution, even Deserialization works - but what if the random XML is like `<a>---</a><a>---</a><b>----</b>`? Then it can't be loaded into an XmlDocument. That's what I would need to do - with deserialization.