# Custom XML serialization - Include class name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm after the following XML serialization output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Body>
    <ExampleObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <EmampleOne>Hello!</EmampleOne>
    </ExampleObject>
  </Body>
</Message>
```

I have the following classes:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Message<T>
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public T Body { get; set; }
    }

[Serializable]
public class ExampleObject
{
    public string EmampleOne { get; set; }
}
```

If I serialize them separately I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Body>
    <EmampleOne>Hello!</EmampleOne>
  </Body>
</Message>
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExampleObject>
  <EmampleOne>Hello!</EmampleOne>
</ExampleObject>
```

So as shown above I'm wanting the inner body to contain the class name `<ExampleObject>`.

I use generics as I need to have different Message Body's, I serialize with the code:

```
var obj = new Message<ExampleObject>
{
    Version = "1.0",
    Body = example
};

var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Message<ExampleObject>));
```

Comment: To do that without implemeting IXmlSerializable will require changes to the object model and using XmlAttributeOverrides - doable but not trivial. I'm not at a PC currently, but might be able to look later. I wonder if writing a DOM directly would be easier...

Comment: FYI, "[Serializable]" is not used by the XML Serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Marc Gravell suggested in his comment, you can use [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx):

```
var xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
attributes.XmlElements
     .Add(new XmlElementAttribute("ExampleObject", typeof (ExampleObject)));
xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(Message<ExampleObject>), "Body", attributes);

var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message<ExampleObject>), xmlOverrides);
```