# Deserialize Child XML Elements as an XML String In .NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

i have a input XML like this

```
<INPUT>
  <A>somevalue<A>
  <B><INPUT><C>somevalue</C></INPUT></B>
</INPUT>
```

and model

```
<XmlRoot("INPUT")>
Public Class Input

  <XmlElement("A")>
  Public a As String

  <XmlElement("B")>
  Public b As String

End Class
```

if i try to parse it by using XmlSerializer i got exception "There is an error in XML Document" and i think the reason is i pass XML in "B" field. i want to serialize "B" field into string variable is this possible by using XmlSerializer ?

Comment: Does [Serialize XML with XML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833263/serialize-xml-with-xml-string) help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have change the data type and XML attribute to String and XMLAnyElement like this

```
<XmlAnyElement("B")>
Public b As XMLElement
```

and create a new property in which i return inner xml of XML element

```
public property bInnerXML as string 

 get
    return b.InnerXml
 end get

end property
```